# How to simulate non-SNI browsers (without SNI support)?

Tags: ssl, client, sni

I'm setting up Apache with several distinct SSL certificates for different domains that reside on the same server (and thus sharing the same IP address).

With [Qualys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) I discovered that there are clients (i.e. [BingBot as of december 2013](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=BingBot&version=Dec%202013)) that do not support the SNI extension.

So I'm thinking about crafting a special default web application that can gather the requests of such clients, but how can I simulate those clients?

I'm on Windows 8, with no access to Linux boxes, if that matters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the most commonly used SSL library, OpenSSL. Windows binaries are available to download.

`openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443` command serves very well to test SSL connection from client side. It doesn't support SNI by default. You can append `-servername domain.com` argument to enable SNI.

Comment: This is true for openssl releases 1.1.0* and earlier. In 1.1.1* builds, s_client sends the "server_name" extension by default (with whatever host was specified in the "-connect" parameter). If you don't want to send "server_name" in the newer version you have to turn it off with "-noservername".

Answer (score 10):

If you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 or earlier version, use `openssl s_client -connect $ip:$port`, and OpenSSL wouldn't enable the SNI extension

If you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1, you need add `-noservername` flag to `openssl s_client`.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to openssl s_client is gnutls-cli

```
gnutls-cli --disable-sni www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and then use the following script to simulate a client not supporting SNI:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => {
    # this disables SNI
    SSL_hostname => '', 
    # These disable certificate verification, so that we get a connection even
    # if the certificate does not match the requested host or is invalid.
    # Do not use in production code !!!
    SSL_verify_mode => 0,
    verify_hostname => 0,
});

# request some data
my $res = $ua->get('https://example.com');

# show headers
# pseudo header Client-SSL-Cert-Subject gives information about the
# peers certificate
print $res->headers_as_string;

# show response including header
# print $res->as_string;
```

By setting SSL_hostname to an empty string you can disable SNI, disabling this line enables SNI again.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer that is cross-platform - despite the asker being on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of using a special default web application simply would not work.

You can't do that because said limited clients not just open a different page, but they fail completely.

1. Consider you have a "default" vhost which a non-SNI client will open just fine.
2. You also have an additional vhost which is supposed to be open by an SNI-supporting client.
3. Obviously, these two must have different hostnames (say, `default.example.com` and `www.example.com`), else Apache or nginx wouldn't know which site to show to which connecting client.

Now, if a non-SNI client tries to open `https://www.example.com`, he'll be presented a certificate from `default.example.com`, which would give him a certificate error. This is a major caveat.

A fix for this error is to make a SAN (multi-domain) certificate that would include both `www.example.com` and `default.example.com`. Then, if a non-SNI client tries to open `https://www.example.com`, he'll be presented with a valid certificate, but even then his `Host:` header would still point to `www.example.com`, and his request will get routed not to `default.example.com` but to `www.example.com`.

As you can see, you either block non-SNI clients completely or forward them to an expected vhost. **There's no sensible option for a default web application.**

Comment: Downvoting. The question is how to simulate requests without sni support.

Comment: @Wes this isn't fair because the question is also about a special default application

Comment: We actively use default applications and it doesn't cause an issue.  The other hosts are in the subject alternative name. So you just can't do that is wrong. (though you do give your own work around) It still doesn't actually answer the question "but how can I simulate those clients" which is both the question title and the actual question in the question. (sorry hard to use correct english here)

Comment: Why should a single answer answer all questions from the original question? Is there a law or a rule?

Comment: I think your taking this too seriously.  Anyway as it stands the only question asked was how to simulate the clients. I've removed the Downvote but I still feel the information is slightly misleading and B doesn't answer the only question that was asked.  Actually I can't remove the downvote, I did try.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to offend. I'm happy to delete my comments if you want. I can't remove the downvote unless you edit the question however.

Answer (score 0):

With a Java HTTP client you can disable the SNI extension by setting the system property `jsse.enableSNIExtension=false`.

More here: [Java TLS: Disable SNI on client handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025494/java-tls-disable-sni-on-client-handshake/64028075)