# Java TLS: Disable SNI on client handshake

Tags: java, kotlin, ssl

I'm trying to create a JVM HTTP client which will not send `server_name` in the Client Handshake (long story, but I'm simulating a legacy system which doesn't support SNI).

Setting the `serverNames` `SSLParameters` doesn't do the trick, I can still see the "Server Name Indication extension" in Wireshark.

```
fun run() {
    val keyStore = keyStore()
    val trustFactory =
        TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
    trustFactory.init(keyStore)
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
    sslContext.init(null, trustFactory.trustManagers, null)

    val httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .sslParameters(sslContext.defaultSSLParameters.apply {
            serverNames = null
        })
        .build()

    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://example.com/hello"))
        .GET()
        .build()

    httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
}
```

Full code in [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/nieldw/c18d7e35135067284540580d3f43f6ce)

How can I stop the client from sending the SNI extension?

Comment: Can you get away with `jsse.enableSNIExtension=false`?

Comment: have you tried setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostNameVerifier.Instance) or setHostnameVerifier(new SSLSkipSNIHostnameVerifier()

Comment: null means use the default (which is to send the name from the URL or open, unless the sysprop says no); to explicity send none [try setting an empty List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903477/#56233394)

Comment: @KevinBoone you are correct. Please feel free to add that as the answer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 unfortunate an empty list doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the setting applying to the whole JVM, try

```
jsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```